# Doubt regarding average kinetic energy of a molecule of an ideal gas

Tags: thermodynamics, kinetic-theory

[image]I understand that average kinetic energy of 1 mole means that every molecule has different kinetic energy due to different velocities so taking the avg gives us a general idea of the K.E of that gas but what do you mean by "average kinetic energy of one molecule".We usually take average to tell us about the central tendency of a range of values so why don't we just say kinetic energy of 1 molecule instead of average kinetic energy of 1 molecule.What is changing for a single molecule for us to say average kinetic energy of 1 molecule?

Comment: Please don’t use photos of text. This one, in particular, is illegible on a mobile device

Answer (score 1):

> What is changing for a single molecule for us to say average kinetic
> energy of 1 molecule?

The speed, and thus kinetic energy, of a single molecule is not constant.

Every molecule is constantly colliding with other molecules whose speeds are higher or lower than the average, resulting in every molecule transferring KE to lower speed molecules causing its speed to decrease, and colliding with higher speed molecules causing its speed to increase. Thus the speed and kinetic energy of every molecule changes in time.

Only if the gas consisted of a single molecule making perfectly elastic collisions with the walls of the container can we say speak of *the* kinetic energy of a single molecule as opposed to the average kinetic energy of a single molecule.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have seen in many places they have defined root mean square velocity for a single molecule though it must ideally be used for a group of molecules.Can we apply the same logic here as well that since velocity of a single molecule keeps changing we can take the root mean square(Vrms)?

Comment: I don't see the purpose of calculating the root mean square of velocity since kinetic energy is the square of velocity.  In other words KE, for each of the 3 independent coordinates x, y, and z, only depends on the change in speed (magnitude of velocity) of the ideal gas molecule and not the change in its direction.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, an individual gas molecule can have any kinetic energy at all. If I tell you that some particular gas molecule has a kinetic energy of 17 Joules, that tells you nothing whatsoever about the rest of the gas.

On the other hand, if I tell you that the *average* kinetic energy of the gas molecules, then that gives you more information, especially if the gas is assumed to be in thermodynamic equilibrium (in which case you know the full distribution of possible energies).